# Hoping for guidance with “display: table-cell;” and padding

Tags: css

I would like the content in the second column to have 10px of space above it.  But when I add "padding-top: 10px;" the content of both columns comes down 10px.  Can anyone suggest a solution?

CSS:

```
#div1 { display: table;}
#div1-1 { display: table-cell; 
   width: 200px; 
   border: 1px solid #aaa; 
}
#div1-2 { display: table-cell; 
   width: 200px; 
   border: 1px solid #aaa; 
   padding-top: 10px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="div1">
<div id="div1-1">Apples</div>
<div id="div1-2">Oranges</div>
</div>
```

Comment: You can add `vertical-align: middle` to `#div1-1`

Comment: It works.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you add float:left; to #div1-1, the first column will remain as it is.

Comment: This works, but making it a floating element causes some side effects.  I'll play around with it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

My solution is to try to add a box in each cell

```css
#myDiv { 
    display: table;
}
#div1 { display: table-row;}
#div1-1{ 
  display: table-cell; 
   width: 200px; 
   border: 1px solid #aaa;
}
#div1-2 { 
   display: table-cell; 
   width: 200px; 
   border: 1px solid #aaa; 
} 
.space{
    height:10px;
    width:100%;
    display:block;
}
.content{
    width:100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="myDiv">
<div id="div1">
  <div id="div1-1">
      <div class="content">Apples</div>
      <div class="space">&nbsp;</div>
   </div>
  <div id="div1-2">
      <div class="space">&nbsp;</div>
      <div class="content">Oranges</div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: You are welcome. Hope that it will fix your problem. :)